# VSC Debuging React, cannot create breakpoints / attach to process

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I've been trying out a lot of the potential fixes from so, but none of them helped me so far.
I cannot get the debugger to attach properly, it does attach, but it doesn't give me breakpoints (breakpoint set but not yet bound).

What I've done so far :

I created the entry in launch.json

```js
{
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch debug client",
      "sourceMaps": true,
      "runtimeExecutable": "node",
      "runtimeArgs": [
        "--inspect-brk",
        "./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js"
      ],
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/client/"
    }
```

That resulted in this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6sZH.png). 

 Is the second --inspect-brk=PORT the one that I should strive to attach to? The second PORT is always random, how would I get the debugger to attach to that? 
It also seems like webpack-dev-server doesn't care about inspect-brk because the client launches and works ...

I'm also not sure if I got webpack-dev-server to build source maps - are they saved in memory?

I did try to set a fixed port, remap sourceMapPathOverrides, set outFiles and setting the program path to no avail. Prior to writing this I did not even see that it tried to generate it's own new port ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone stumbles upon this: Webpack-dev-server is **already launched in debugger mode**, and the only way to currently attach to that process (as far as I could find) is through the browser.
You will need to **install a debugger extension for vsc** for the browser that you are using (currently only available for chrome and firefox). Then you can just attach / launch to the url that webpack-dev-server is starting on and vscode will hook into that instance.

#### Example

launch.json

```
    {
      "type": "firefox",
      "name": "firefox debug",
      "request": "launch",
      "url": "http://localhost:8080",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/client"
    }
```